# I am trying to SIFT from this image

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, sift, feature-descriptor

I wrote my own implementation of SIFT (Scale-Invariant Feature Transform) and then I rotate an image and match points with the original image. However, the output results don't seem to align correctly, and I'm not sure where it went wrong. I suspect that there might be an issue with how the SIFT function is defined.

I would appreciate any assistance you can provide.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from cv2 import KeyPoint

def find_local_maxima(src, ksize):
    (h, w) = src.shape
    pad_img = np.zeros((h + ksize, w + ksize))
    pad_img[ksize // 2:h + ksize // 2, ksize // 2:w + ksize // 2] = src
    dst = np.zeros((h, w))

    for row in range(h):
        for col in range(w):
            max_val = np.max(pad_img[row: row + ksize, col:col + ksize])
            if max_val == 0:
                continue
            if src[row, col] == max_val:
                dst[row, col] = src[row, col]

    return dst


def my_padding(src, filter):
    (h, w) = src.shape
    if isinstance(filter, tuple):
        (h_pad, w_pad) = filter
    else:
        (h_pad, w_pad) = filter.shape
    h_pad = h_pad // 2
    w_pad = w_pad // 2
    padding_img = np.zeros((h + h_pad * 2, w + w_pad * 2))
    padding_img[h_pad:h + h_pad, w_pad:w + w_pad] = src

    # repetition padding
    # up
    padding_img[:h_pad, w_pad:w_pad + w] = src[0, :]
    # down
    padding_img[h_pad + h:, w_pad:w_pad + w] = src[h - 1, :]
    # left
    padding_img[:, :w_pad] = padding_img[:, w_pad:w_pad + 1]
    # right
    padding_img[:, w_pad + w:] = padding_img[:, w_pad + w - 1:w_pad + w]

    return padding_img

def my_filtering(src, filter):
    (h, w) = src.shape
    (f_h, f_w) = filter.shape

    
    # print('<filter>')
    # print(filter)

    
    pad_img = my_padding(src, filter)

    dst = np.zeros((h, w))
    for row in range(h):
        for col in range(w):
            dst[row, col] = np.sum(pad_img[row:row + f_h, col:col + f_w] * filter)

    return dst

def get_my_sobel():
    sobel_x = np.dot(np.array([[1], [2], [1]]), np.array([[-1, 0, 1]]))
    sobel_y = np.dot(np.array([[-1], [0], [1]]), np.array([[1, 2, 1]]))
    return sobel_x, sobel_y

def calc_derivatives(src):
    # calculate Ix, Iy
    sobel_x, sobel_y = get_my_sobel()
    Ix = my_filtering(src, sobel_x)
    Iy = my_filtering(src, sobel_y)
    return Ix, Iy

def SIFT(src):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY).astype(np.float32)

    print("get keypoint")
    dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray, 3, 3, 0.04)
    dst[dst < 0.01 * dst.max()] = 0
    dst = find_local_maxima(dst, 21)
    dst = dst / dst.max()
    
    
    y, x = np.nonzero(dst)

    keypoints = []
    for i in range(len(x)):
        # x, y, size, angle, response, octave, class_id
        pt_x = int(x[i]) #point x
        pt_y = int(y[i]) #point y
        size = None
        key_angle = -1.
        response = dst[y[i], x[i]] 
        octave = 0 
        class_id = -1
        keypoints.append(KeyPoint(pt_x, pt_y, size, key_angle, response, octave, class_id))

    print('get Ix and Iy...')
    Ix, Iy = calc_derivatives(gray)

    print('calculate angle and magnitude')
    # magnitude / orientation 
    magnitude = np.sqrt((Ix ** 2) + (Iy ** 2))
    angle = np.arctan2(Iy, Ix)  # radian 
    angle = np.rad2deg(angle)  # radian 
    angle = (angle + 360) % 360  

    # keypoint 
    print('calculate orientation assignment')
    for i in range(len(keypoints)):
        x, y = keypoints[i].pt
        orient_hist = np.zeros(36, ) 
        for row in range(-8, 8):
            for col in range(-8, 8):
                p_y = int(y + row)
                p_x = int(x + col)
                if p_y < 0 or p_y > src.shape[0] - 1 or p_x < 0 or p_x > src.shape[1] - 1:
                    continue 
                gaussian_weight = np.exp((-1 / 16) * (row ** 2 + col ** 2))
                orient_hist[int(angle[p_y, p_x] // 10)] += magnitude[p_y, p_x] * gaussian_weight
        
        max_val = np.max(orient_hist)
        keypoints[i].angle = float((np.argmax(orient_hist) * 10) % 360)

        for j in range(36):
            if orient_hist[j] > max_val * 0.8 and j != np.argmax(orient_hist):
                new_keypoint = KeyPoint(pt_x, pt_y, size, (j * 10) % 360, response, octave, class_id)
                keypoints.append(new_keypoint)

    print('calculate descriptor')
    descriptors = np.zeros((len(keypoints), 128))  # 8 orientation * 4 * 4 = 128 dimensions

    for i in range(len(keypoints)):
        x, y = keypoints[i].pt
        theta = np.deg2rad(keypoints[i].angle)
        
        cos_angle = np.cos(theta)
        sin_angle = np.sin(theta)

        for row in range(-8, 8):
            for col in range(-8, 8):
                
                row_rot = np.round((cos_angle * col) + (sin_angle * row))
                col_rot = np.round((cos_angle * col) - (sin_angle * row))

                p_y = int(y + row_rot)
                p_x = int(x + col_rot)
                if p_y < 0 or p_y > (src.shape[0] - 1) \
                        or p_x < 0 or p_x > (src.shape[1] - 1):
                    continue
                
                gaussian_weight = np.exp((-1 / 16) * (row_rot ** 2 + col_rot ** 2))
                weight = magnitude[p_y,p_x] * gaussian_weight
                bin_num = int(angle[p_y, p_x] // 45)
                cell_num_row = int((row + 8) // 4)
                cell_num_col = int((col + 8) // 4)
                descriptors[i][32 * cell_num_row + 8 * cell_num_col:32 * cell_num_row + 8 * (cell_num_col + 1)][
                    bin_num] += weight
    return keypoints, descriptors


def main():
    src = cv2.imread("zebra.png")
    src_rotation = cv2.rotate(src, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)

    kp1, des1 = SIFT(src)
    kp2, des2 = SIFT(src_rotation)

    ## Matching 
    bf = cv2.BFMatcher_create(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
    des1 = des1.astype(np.uint8)
    des2 = des2.astype(np.uint8)

    matches = bf.match(des1, des2)
    matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)

    result = cv2.drawMatches(src, kp1, src_rotation, kp2, matches[:20], outImg=None, flags=2)
    
    
    cv2.imshow('sift', result)
    cv2.waitKey()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: you're following bad advice. your code lacks "Lowe's ratio test" and the number of keypoints appears to be extremely small. since you reimplemented SIFT yourself (or appear to be trying that), you need to make sure that's done correctly. compare to a reference implementation.